# Probability of sum of independent normally distributed variables

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution

The weight of an adult swan is normally distributed with a mean of 30 pounds and a standard deviation of 9.8 pounds. A farmer randomly selected 36 swans and loaded them into his truck. What is the probability that this flock of swans weighs > 1010 pounds?

How can I solve this question? I can do it for one swan but how can I do it for a flock?

Comment: Because this is a homework/self-study question, you should add the `self-study` tag. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: Not only should you see the `self-study` tag as Patrick suggests, you should add it to your tags, read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and modify your question to follow the guidelines on asking such questions. In particular, you'll need to clearly identify what you've done to solve the problem yourself, and indicate the specific help you need at the point you struck difficulty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't require any appeal to the central limit theorem, you only need to use the fact that a sum of independent normal random variables is itself normal with mean and variance equal to the sum of the means and variances of the summands.  So if $X_i$ is the weight of the $i^\text{th}$ swan we have $S \equiv\sum_{i=1}^{36} X_i \sim$ normal$(\mu = 1080, \sigma^2 = 3457.44)$.  Therefore

\begin{align}
P(S > 1010) &= 1 - P(S \leq 1010) \\
&= 1 - P \left ( \frac{S - 1080}{\sqrt{3457.44}} \leq \frac{1010 - 1080}{\sqrt{3457.44}} \right ) \\
&= 1 - P(Z \leq -1.19) 
\end{align}

where $Z \sim$ normal$(0, 1)$.  The rest can be done by either using software or consulting a standard normal table.